# Complicated SQL query performance issue (group by, case statement)

Tags: mysql, sql

The sql query (at the end of the post) has serious performance issues. It takes up to 1 second on a small data set. I'm quite new to SQL. Could anyone give me some advices on how to optimize the query? I have two tables, user table and notification table.

**User table:**

> user_id, first_name, profile_image

**Notification table:**

> category, to_uid, from_id, title_id, create_time (linux timestamp)

I want to return aggregated notifications for a specified to_uid group by combinations of category and title_id fields. There is a category called 'special'. If the category is called 'special', then we shouldn't aggregate that row. If a row's category is 'special', it's from_id and title_id fields are always NULL.

Notification sample data:

```
category, to_uid,   from_id, title_id, create_time (linux timestamp)
like_post, 4,          3,       5,       123456
follow,    4,          3,       4,       123457
like_post, 4,          5,       5,       123478
special,   4,          NULL,    NULL,    123467 
special,   4,          NULL,    NULL,    123468
```

Expected result:

```
category,  to_uid,  from_id,   title_id,     first_name_list
like_post,   4,        3,5          5,         uid_3_first_name,uid_5_first_name 
follow,      4,        3,           4,         uid_3_first_name
special,     4,        NULL,        NULL,      NULL
special,     4,        NULL,        NULL,      123468
```

---

```
SELECT n.category, n.to_uid, n.title_id, n.title, n.create_time, 
    CASE WHEN n.category <> "category1"
        THEN GROUP_CONCAT(u.first_name)
    END user_name_list,
    GROUP_CONCAT(n.from_id) from_id_list, GROUP_CONCAT(u.profile_image) profile_image_list,
    CASE WHEN n.category IN ("category2")
            THEN concat_ws("_", n.title_id, n.category)
         ELSE concat_ws("_", "uni", n.id, n.category)
    END AS group_id
FROM notification n, user u
WHERE CASE WHEN n.category <> "category1"
            THEN n.from_id = u.user_id
           ELSE 1 = 1
      END
AND to_uid = 20
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY n.create_time DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Please use `EXPLAIN` (google it) and it will tell you what indexes are being used. Then you can increase performance by adding the necessary indexes

Comment: The problem is caused by group by group_id. group_id is generated in Select query. How can I add index for that?

Comment: How? group_id is a derived field in select query:   CASE WHEN n.category IN ("category2")
            THEN concat_ws("_", n.title_id, n.category)
         ELSE concat_ws("_", "uni", n.id, n.category)
    END AS group_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use LEFT JOIN instead

```
FROM notification n LEFT JOIN user u 
   ON n.category <> "category1" AND n.from_id = u.user_id
WHERE
to_uid = 20
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. WHEN is not valid mysql keyword. The condition needs to be: if(n.category <> "category1") then n.from_id = u.user_id;  else {Don't do join as n.from_id is null)

Comment: Thanks. That improves the speed a lot. Do you know how to optimize the limit 20 part? It's used for pagination. The table doesn't have a consecutive incremental id.

Comment: LIMIT 1 ,20 or LIMIT 21,20. You have to specify range of records you need. From index and amount of records